# Loading unnecessary directX files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directx

When I run my application I get different output compare to my colleague's.

The different part is Loading DirectX & Unloading them again part.

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10core.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1core.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxdiagn.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1core.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10.dll'

Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10core.dll'

Above is the difference( just part of it ).

** Q1: Why load all directX related dll files and unload them again?

** Q2: They're not even loaded in my colleague's system. And runs good(even faster). What causes to load them and how can I make it not to load?

And I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, VisualStudio 2010, DirectX.

Comment: what are the gfx cards on both machines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the reason why it is Unloading is because it can't find the [pdb debug file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx) that is required for debugging.  You could recreate those or just compile the pdb files.

As to why they are loading, something in your project has a reference to DirectX.  What app are you building?  Some newer frameworks have DirectX/Direct3D in them like WPF, XNA etc.

As to why your collegue doesn't see it... Are you both building debug builds? (you won't see the psdb stuff on release mode).  Do you have extra projects in your solution or the same solution?  The pdb errors happen alot.  If you just figure out what is using DirectX or generate the pdbs or build in Release those messages will go away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer after all. My collegue and I use same project settings(from SVN) and both are debug mode.